# Minimize the Squared $ {L}_{2} $ Norm of a Vector With Linear Equality and Inequality Constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

Given the following Convex Optimization Problem:

### The Problem

\begin{align*}
    \text{minimize}     & \quad & \left\| x \right\|_{2}^{2} \\
    \text{subject to}   & \quad & x - a \leq 0 \\
    \text{}             & \quad & \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x = b
\end{align*}

Below I solved it using 2 methods:

1. [The KKT Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2375679/33).
2. [The Dual Problem Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2375690/33).

The full code is in my [Mathematics Q2375676 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q2375676).
The code is validated using CVX.

Comment: By the way, you don't need Slater's condition, as the constraint set is polyhedral. See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Regularity_conditions_.28or_constraint_qualifications.29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Dual Problem Solution

The Lagrangian is given by:

$$ L \left( x, \lambda, \nu \right) = {x}^{T} x + {\lambda}^{T} \left( x - a \right) + \nu \left( \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x - b \right) = {x}^{T} x + \left( 
\lambda + \nu \boldsymbol{1} \right)^{T} x -{\lambda}^{T} a - \nu b $$

The Dual Function is given by:

$$ g \left( \lambda, \nu \right) = \inf_{x} L \left( x, \lambda, \nu \right) $$

Looking at the term related to $ x $:

$$ \inf_{x} {x}^{T} x + \left( \lambda + \nu \boldsymbol{1} \right)^{T} x $$

Which is a quadratic form of $ x $ with its minimizer given by:
$$ {x}^{\ast} = -\frac{1}{2} \left( 
\lambda + \nu \boldsymbol{1} \right) $$

Its minimum given by
$$ {{x}^{\ast}}^{T} {x}^{\ast} + \left( 
\lambda + \nu \boldsymbol{1} \right)^{T} {x}^{\ast} = -\frac{1}{4} \left( 
\lambda + \nu \boldsymbol{1} \right)^{T} \left( \lambda + \nu \boldsymbol{1} \right) $$

Hence the Dual Problem is given by:

\begin{align*}
\text{maximize} & \quad & -\frac{1}{4} \left( 
\lambda + \nu \boldsymbol{1} \right)^{T} \left( \lambda + \nu \boldsymbol{1} \right) - {\lambda}^{T} a - \nu b \\
\text{subject to} & \quad & \lambda \succeq 0 
\end{align*}

The problem is Concave in $ \left( \lambda, \nu \right) $ hence it is a convex problem.
It can be solved by a Quadratic Programming as:

$$ \left( 
\lambda + \nu \boldsymbol{1} \right)^{T} \left( \lambda + \nu \boldsymbol{1} \right) = {\left\| E v \right\|}_{2}^{2} = {v}^{T} {E}^{T} E v = {v}^{T} H v $$

Where $ v = {\left[ \lambda, \nu \right]}^{T}, \; E = \left[ I, \boldsymbol{1} \right], \; H = {E}^{T} E $. Then the problem becomes:

$$
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} & \quad & \frac{1}{4} {v}^{T} H v + {v}^{T} f \\
\text{subject to} & \quad & A v \preceq 0 
\end{align*}
$$

Where $ A = - \left[ I, \boldsymbol{0} \right], \; f = {\left[ a, b \right]}^{T} $.

The above can directly solved by MATLAB's [`quadprog()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html). Then $ {x}^{\ast} = -0.5 E v $.

Comment: It looks concave to me.

Comment: No! It's just $-\tfrac{1}{4}\|\lambda+\nu \vec{1}\|_2^2$

Comment: And if it's convex when you _don't_ open the terms, it still is when you do.

Comment: No, you still maximize with respect to both simultaneously. It is jointly concave in both.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, I think you can delete all comments. I have updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

### KKT Solution

For the solution it will be assumed, for simplicity, that $ {a}_{1} \leq {a}_{2} \leq \ldots \leq {a}_{n} $.

The Lagrangian of the problem is given by:

$$ L \left( x, \lambda, \nu \right) = {x}^{T} x + {\lambda}^{T} \left( x - a \right) + \nu \left( \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x - b \right) $$

The KKT System is given by:

\begin{align*}
    \nabla L \left( x, \lambda, \nu \right) = 2x + \lambda + \nu \boldsymbol{1} & = 0 & \text{(1)} \\
    {\lambda}_{i} \left( {x}_{i} - {a}_{i} \right) & = 0 & \text{(2)} \\
    \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x & = b & \text{(3)} \\
    \lambda & \succeq 0 & \text{(4)}
\end{align*}

Define the sets $ A = \left\{ i \mid {x}_{i} \neq {a}_{i} \right\} $ and $ B = \left\{ i \mid {x}_{i} = {a}_{i} \right\} $.
Looking at $ A $ yields $ \forall j \in A, \: {\lambda}_{j} = 0 $ which means:

\begin{align*}
    2 {x}_{A} + \nu \boldsymbol{1} & = 0 & \text{} \\
    & \Rightarrow 2 \boldsymbol{1}^{T} {x}_{A} + \nu \boldsymbol{1}^{T} \boldsymbol{1} = 0 & \text{Summing both ends} \\
    & = 2 \left( b - \boldsymbol{1}^{T} {x}_{B} \right) + \nu \left| A \right| & \text{By (3)} \\
    & \Rightarrow \nu = -2 \frac{b - \boldsymbol{1}^{T} {x}_{B}}{\left| A \right|} & \text{} \\
    & \Rightarrow {{x}_{A}}_{i} = \frac{b - \boldsymbol{1}^{T} {x}_{B}}{\left| A \right|}
\end{align*}

Where $ {x}_{A} $ is a vector composed of elements which are in set $ A $ by their indices.
The intuition is that for any $ {x}_{i} $ such that $ i \in A $ the value is the mean of the residual $ b - \boldsymbol{1}^{T} {x}_{B} $.

Looking at $ B $ suggests $ \forall i \in B, \: {x}_{i} = {a}_{i} $ which yields:

\begin{align*}
    2 {a}_{i} + {\lambda}_{i} - 2 \frac{b - \boldsymbol{1}^{T} {x}_{B}}{\left| A \right|} & = 0 & \text{By (1)} \\
    & \Rightarrow {\lambda}_{i} = 2 \left( \frac{b - \boldsymbol{1}^{T} {x}_{B}}{\left| A \right|} - {a}_{i} \right)
\end{align*}

From constraint (4) the above is valid only in the case:
$$ i : {\lambda}_{i} = 2 \left( \frac{b - \boldsymbol{1}^{T} {x}_{B}}{\left| A \right|} - {a}_{i} \right) \geq 0 $$

Since, for the case with no constraints of $ a $ the solution would be given by the mean, namely $ x = \frac{b}{n} \boldsymbol{1} $ the logic is to increase $ \left| A \right| $.

Since $ {a}_{i} $ are sorted in ascending order one could search for the following:

- Start with $ A = \left\{ 1, 2, \ldots, n \right\} $, $ B = \emptyset $ and $ \forall i \; {x}_{i} = \frac{b}{n} $.
- Do Loop $ i = 1, 2, \ldots n $:

  - If $ \left( \frac{b - \boldsymbol{1}^{T} {x}_{B}}{\left| A \right|} \leq {a}_{ {A}_{i} } \right) $ break the loop.
  - Move $ {A}_{i} $ to $ B $.
- Calculate $ x $ as above.

Remarks:

- If at the end $ A = \emptyset $ the problem isn't feasible as feasibility requires $ \boldsymbol{1}^{T} a \geq b $.
- The solution is non negative, namely $ x \geq 0 $ assuming $ a \geq 0 $.